# WebLogic doesn't loads class despite being on $domain/lib

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I'm trying to add a AS400 jar to WebLogic classpath. I'm putting the jt400.jar inside $domain/lib/ as indicated by the readme.txt found in there. And when server starts I can see the line:

`<Sep 14, 2017 7:12:28 PM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <The following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
{$domain}/lib/jt400.jar.>`

But, when I'm testing my datasource stills throws the error message:

```
weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver for datasource 'MyDataSource'
```

I have verified that the class is indeed inside the given jar.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand what was happening. I forgot to add to the question that the WebLogic had several managed cluster servers. After trying various approachs, I realized the error only occured when I selected one of the clusters I wanted that datasource to serve.

So in the end, the servers from that cluster also need the jar to connect to the selected datasource.